# Kivy: horizontal scrollable labels inside a GridLayout

Tags: python, scroll, kivy

I am trying to adapt the code from the [ScrollView doc](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html) to have get scrollable labels on the horizontal axis inside a GridLayout. The GridLayout shouldn't be scrollable it, just the labels within it.

For my app, I can't use kv language (either in .kv or the builder), so the code has to be in python.

```py
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.app import runTouchApp

layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10)

for i in range(10):
    label = Label(text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", height = 30, size_hint_x=None, width=400)
    label.bind(minimum_width=label.setter('width'))
    root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, 1), size=(label.width, label.height))
    root.add_widget(label)
    layout.add_widget(root)


runTouchApp(layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, this is working:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        layout  = GridLayout (cols=3)
        for i in range(3):
            l = Label(font_size=15, size_hint_x= None, width=300, text="This is a very looooooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng text. Indeed it is a very loooooooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng text")
            l.bind(size_hint_min_x=l.setter('width'))
            scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 400), pos_hint={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5})
            scroll.add_widget(l)

            layout.add_widget(scroll)
        return layout


Test().run()
```